# Excluding some dependency from mvn dependency:resolve

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin

In my `pom.xml` of `com.test:Service:1.0`, I have a dependency on some local jar: `com.test:Parser:1.0`

I want to resolve all dependencies except for it, since I install it manually to my local maven. Resolve command:

`mvn -B dependency:resolve -DincludeParents=true`

But it fails on:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Service: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.test:Service:jar:1.0: Could not find
>   artifact com.test:Parser:jar:1.0 in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Then I tried to add the options

`-DexcludeGroupIds=com.test -DexcludeArtifactIds=Parser`

but am still getting the same error. Am I misusing the options?

Reference: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html

Comment: Apparently this seems to be a known issue, unhandled for a couple of years.. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-568

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to simply be a bug. See

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-568

https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/pull/2

The solution, as proposed in the above threads, is to use a different library: https://github.com/qaware/go-offline-maven-plugin

In your `pom.xml` add the plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.qaware.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>go-offline-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dynamicDependencies>
                    </dynamicDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Then use the command `mvn de.qaware.maven:go-offline-maven-plugin:resolve-dependencies` with the required options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 3.8.6 and it looks like go-offline works with exclude*, but resolve does not:

`mvn dependency:go-offline -DexcludeGroupIds=com.test`

According to: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html

- **dependency:go-offline** tells Maven to resolve everything this project is dependent on (dependencies, plugins, reports) in preparation for going offline.
- **dependency:resolve** tells Maven to resolve all dependencies and displays the version.